# Select data from two identical tables using WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have this example:

```
CREATE TABLE ForgeRock
    (`id` int, `productName` varchar(7), `description` varchar(55))
;

INSERT INTO ForgeRock (`id`, `productName`, `description`)
VALUES (1, 'OpenIDM', 'Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions'),
       (2, 'OpenAM', 'Full-featured access management'),
       (3, 'OpenDJ', 'Robust LDAP server for Java');

CREATE TABLE ForgeRock2
    (`id` int, `productName` varchar(7), `description` varchar(55))
;

INSERT INTO ForgeRock2 (`id`, `productName`, `description`)
VALUES (1, 'OpenIDM', 'Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions'),
       (2, 'OpenAM', 'Full-featured access management'),
       (3, 'OpenDJ', 'Robust LDAP server for Java');
```

Why this query gives me three entries?

```
SELECT
  ForgeRock.productName,
  ForgeRock.description
FROM
  ForgeRock, ForgeRock2
WHERE
  ForgeRock.id = 2;
```

Output:

```
productname | description
---------------------------------------------
OpenAM      | Full-featured access management
OpenAM      | Full-featured access management
OpenAM      | Full-featured access management
```

Here is an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8bbf8/3/0) for the example

Can anyone give an explanation why the result contains 3 entries ?!

Comment: Never use commas in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit `join` syntax with an `on`.  You are doing a Cartesian product.  What other result would you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query

```
SELECT
  ForgeRock.productName,
  ForgeRock.description
FROM
  ForgeRock, ForgeRock2
 WHERE
 ForgeRock.id = 2;
```

It is a `CROSS JOIN` what means `show every data combination from ForgeRock and ForgeRock2`. For `ForgeRock` you added a condition  `ForgeRock.id = 2` so the result is every combination from  `ForgeRock2` with row `ForgeRock.id = 2`. In table `ForgeRock2` you have 3 rows so you see 3 rows in the result.

To make it properly you need join as below

```
   SELECT
      ForgeRock.productName,
      ForgeRock.description
    FROM ForgeRock
     join  ForgeRock2 on ForgeRock2.id = ForgeRock.id
     WHERE
     ForgeRock.id = 2;
```

or you can also use old standard (but I recommended above standard)

```
 SELECT
      ForgeRock.productName,
      ForgeRock.description
    FROM
      ForgeRock, ForgeRock2
     WHERE
     ForgeRock.id = 2
     and ForgeRock2.id = ForgeRock.id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Its a cross join you are doing. So the entry in table 1 with id=2 is mapped to each and every entry of table 2 i.e 3 entries and hence you get 3 rows
If you still want to use cross join -

```
SELECT
  ForgeRock.productName,
  ForgeRock.description
FROM
  ForgeRock, ForgeRock2
 WHERE
 ForgeRock.id = 2 and forgeRock2.id = 2
```

Better solution -

```
SELECT
  a.productName,
  a.description
FROM
  ForgeRock a JOIN  ForgeRock2 b
  ON a.id = b.id
 WHERE
 a.id = 2
```